SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import. - while importing styles from external package
I have a React application which use custom Webpack config. I want to add library for components, specifically @carbon/react in version 1.62.1, the newest available.
My application uses React 18, Webpack 5, Node 22, sass 1.77.2, so everything is up to date.
Documentation (https://carbondesignsystem.com/developing/frameworks/react/#getting-started) says that if you want to use styles for component you have to add code:
@use '@carbon/react/scss/components/button';


So I added to the first line of my scss file. And here is the magic, I'm getting this error:
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
8  │ ┌ @forward '@carbon/layout/scss/spacing' show $spacing, $spacing-01, $spacing-02,
9  │ │   $spacing-03, $spacing-04, $spacing-05, $spacing-06, $spacing-07, $spacing-08,
10 │ │   $spacing-09, $spacing-10, $spacing-11, $spacing-12, $spacing-13,
11 │ │   $fluid-spacing-01, $fluid-spacing-02, $fluid-spacing-03, $fluid-spacing-04,
12 │ │   // Deprecated
13 │ │   $layout,
14 │ │   $layout-01, $layout-02, $layout-03, $layout-04, $layout-05, $layout-06,
15 │ │   $layout-07;
   │ └────────────^
   ╵
  node_modules/@carbon/styles/scss/_spacing.scss 8:1                  @use
  node_modules/@carbon/styles/scss/components/button/_vars.scss 8:1   @forward
  node_modules/@carbon/styles/scss/components/button/_index.scss 8:1  @forward
  node_modules/@carbon/react/scss/components/button/_index.scss 9:1   @use
  /react-application/resources/styles/test/carbon.scss 1:1            root stylesheet


As you can see, the stacktrace shows several files which uses @use and @forward and these are correct imports. But at the end there is an error.
If I go to to this file in node_modules and change
@forward '@carbon/layout/scss/spacing' into @forward '@carbon/layout/scss/_spacing.scss' - an error doesn't occure anymore (at least this error, but there are the same errors from another files), but of course it is not a solution.
My webpack config is very simple, for scss I have rule test: /\.scss$/ which use sass-loader (there is also css-loader and postcss-loader here, but I think that config for it doesn't matter):
{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
},

My resolve section in webpack config looks like this:
webappConfig.resolve = {
    modules: [
        '/path-to-my-project/src',
        'node_modules',
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.scss'],
};

Any advise? I don't know how to deal with that and I think maybe there is a missing additional configuration in my webpack?
I tried to add config in sass-loader.
I searched in GH issues, but the only one topic with very similar issue was closed without any meaningful solution.
But I failed with any potential solution.

It seems like a an issue with sass and not the webpack packaging itself, when I run sass file.scss in cli tool that has the @use carbon, I get the same error, after adding --load-path flag specifying the node_modules path it works. need to check how to mimic that to webpack

Adding the node_modules folder in webpack config might solve the issue
{
  loader: 'sass-loader', // Compiles Sass to CSS
  options: {
    // Add `node_modules` to the `includePaths` array
    sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
  },
}

I am using rollup so I installed a plugin called postcss and it worked
postcss({
  extensions: ['.scss'],
  extract: false,
  minimize: true,
  sourceMap: true,
  use: [
    ['sass', {
       includePaths: [
         path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
       ]
    }]
  ]
})

